# UIView animation, how make it smooth?

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiview

I try to implement simple animation to change view position I use this code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations: ^{
self.greenIm.frame = CGRectMake(self.roundView.frame.origin.x, self.roundView.frame.origin.y -   110, 60, 60);
 self.greenIm.layer.cornerRadius = self.greenIm.frame.size.height / 2;
}
```

But what I see, my rounded view self.greenIm go to new position without rounding and only at the end  stay rounded, looks bad.

Later I want change size of another View but I need same center:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations: ^{
self.cup.frame = CGRectMake(self.cup.frame.origin.x, self.cupImage.frame.origin.y, self.cup.frame.size.width - 20, self.cup.frame.size.height - 20);
self.cup.center = self.centerPoint;
}
```

Here I see same, first view change size later centering.

How fix it ? How I understand UIView animation anime all properties not in one time. Please help.

Comment: To increase Duration time of Animation to Make Smooth

Comment: I need fast animation.

Comment: setting frame and center in one animation might not be a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you first problem, Apple documentation says that you can animate the properties, which are animatable.

> A block object containing the changes to commit to the views. This is where you programmatically change any **animatable properties** of the views in your view hierarchy. This block takes no parameters and has no return value. This parameter must not be NULL.

If you see the documentation for **UIView** properties, you will find that **layer** is not animatable. You need to use Core Animation to achieve this. Use the below code. I am using a **UILabel** for this sample code.  See if this helps.

```
  CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
  [anim setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:10.0]]];
  lblView.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0; 
  [anim setDuration:6];
  [lblView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"move"];
```

In this very same fashion you can create another animation object for *position* property and change the frame as desired. Add that animation to *layer* and both animation will start in parallel.

Comment: I solve my problem and now working smooth. Standard animation don't like change size when move and I don't need that I have mistake in sizes, but your idea is good and I try in the future.