# Unable to make view ease in and out with UIAnimation block

Tags: ios, objective-c, uianimation

I'm trying to make a view appear and disappear off the screen smoothly. However, the animation block isn't working.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:2.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         _tutorial.hidden = false;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                                               delay:3.0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              _tutorial.hidden = true;
                                          }
                                          completion:NULL];
                     }];
```

When I replace the animation block with just `_tutorial.hidden = false;`, the view shows, so I'm assuming I set up the block incorrectly.

Comment: try in `options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, *hidden* is not animatable property through *UIView* animation blocks. See [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418554/uiview-animation-how-make-it-smooth/25420640#25420640) addressing a different question.

Secondly you need to put the hiding code inside a method and then call the it from completion block.(I am not sure about the reason but it haunted me long ago). But again you can't achieve it via *hidden* property, you need to use *alpha* for it

> [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
>                            delay:2.0
>                          options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
>                       animations:^{
>
> ```
>                     //_tutorial.hidden = NO;
>                    _tutorial.alpha = 1.0;
>                 }
>                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
>
>                    [self disappearTheView];
>
>                 }];
> ```
>
> -(void)disappearTheView {
>
> ```
>      [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
>                                           delay:3.0
>                                         options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
>                                      animations:^{
>                                          //_tutorial.hidden = YES;
>                                         _tutorial.alpha = 0;
>                                      }
>                                      completion:NULL];
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Use alpha instead of hidden when using animation

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:2.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         _tutorial.alpha = 1.0f;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                                               delay:3.0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              _tutorial.alpha = 0.0f;
                                          }
                                          completion:NULL];
                     }];
```